# Highlight the newly added row in clr-datagrid

Tags: html, datagrid, angular5, vmware-clarity

I have used clarity UI in my project and i have come across an issue where i want to select the row which is currently added to the clr-datagrid table .I've used clr-DgSelected directive and it gives me a select checkbox which i don't need and if i use [(clrDgSingleSelected)]="selectedUser" this will give me a radio option and it lets me to select the particular column with the radio option checked but the problem is not the radio button or checkbox i just want to highlight the newly added row how i can achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated Thank You

Comment: Clarity's datagrid doesn't have a specific option to "add" rows, so what do you mean by "newly added"? Could you post an example of what you're trying to do, maybe on a plunker? Because as is, your question is hard to answer without any context.

Comment: Questions without code make it hard to help. You probably need to manage it yourself, by adding a custom property on each record that you want to show as highlighted, and in the HTML you add a css to `clr-dg-row`if the record calls for it.

Answer (score 2):

Since Clarity doesn't have the concept of a newly added row, you need to add that concept yourself. Each record could have a `isNew` or `showHighlight` property that would allow you to add a CSS class that will highlight it

```
<clr-dg-row *ngFor="let user of users" [class.highlight]="user.isNew">
    <clr-dg-cell>{{user.id}}</clr-dg-cell>
    <clr-dg-cell>{{user.name}}</clr-dg-cell>
    <clr-dg-cell>{{user.creation | date}}</clr-dg-cell>
    <clr-dg-cell>{{user.color}}</clr-dg-cell>
</clr-dg-row>
```